# ipython in visual studio with pyLDAvis

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

I can run this code in a Jupyter notebook and it visualizes nicely:

```
lda = gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.load('C:/bla/TopicModelling/model.gensim')
lda_display = pyLDAvis.gensim.prepare(lda, corpus, dictionary, sort_topics=False)
pyLDAvis.display(lda_display)
```

I configured Visual Studio 2017 as well to run in IPython interactive mode. However, when I run the code there nothing shows. However, code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 10)
y = x ** 2
plt.plot(x, y, 'r', x, x ** 3, 'g', x, x ** 4, 'b')
plt.show()
```

shows a graph. What am I missing? Can I use Visual Studio or do I have to use Jupyter notebooks? Thanks!